# Design Horizontal Line on UiView

Tags: ios, uiview, line

anyone can 'tell me how you draw a horizontal line on the UIView by code or by other methods? I need this line to create a separator
Thank you all

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably use to create a UIView with the height, width, and color you want your separator to have and make it a subview of the view in question. In other words, make a 1 or 2 point tall UIView and use it as your separator. Position it using constraints or manually setting its frame.

Comment: Could you add en example?

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, add an UILabel and set the text to ---------- or **______** or ======== or whatever looks good. You can adjust the thickness and style by setting the font or the color by setting the text color. Make sure you set the line breaks to "clip" (NSLineBreakByClipping) or you may end up with ellipsis (...) if you enter more characters than the label can show.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the UIView's drawRect: method to draw a 1 pixel stroke at the bottom of the view to act as a separator.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRrect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height - 1);
    CGPoint endPoint   = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x + rect.size.width - 1, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height - 1);

    CGContextSaveState(context);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapSquare);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0); // Set the line width here
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, startPoint.x + 0.5, startPoint.y + 0.5);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, endPoint.x + 0.5, startPoint.y + 0.5);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGContextRestoreState(context);
}
```